# How to create a list with array subfields in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, filter, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Assume a collection where each document contains an array `my_array` consisting of multiple dictionaries. Each dictionary in the array contains itself an entry with key `my_key`.

How can I efficiently update all documents in the collection, creating a new field `my_list` per document which shall contain all `my_key` values of the dictionaries in the array?

Update with an example document:

```
{
'_id': '123',
'irrelevant_field_1': '1',
'irrelevant_field_2': '2',
'my_array': [
            {'my_key': 'a', 'other_key_1': 'b'},
            {'my_key': 'aa', 'other_key_2': 'bb'},
            {'my_key': 'aaa', 'other_key_3': 'bbb'}
]
}
```

I would like to update with a new field `'my_list': ['a', 'aa', 'aaa']` at the same level as `my_array`.

Comment: Some visibility would go a long way to help solve this problem; please add a sample document and the expected outcome from the above write operation.

Comment: @chridam I provided an example, I hope it is clear now.

Comment: You could use an `$out` pipeline to update in an aggregation framework where the full pipeline looks like `db.collection.aggregate( [
                      { $addFields : { my_list : "$my_array.my_key" } },
                      { $out : "collection" }
                  ] )` just like in this possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field

Comment: @chridam this works, what I didn't know about is that I can use simply "$my_array.my_key". Is it possible to obtain the same outcome also with an UpdateMany operation instead of an aggregation? If you provide your comment as an answer I will gladly accept it. I would also be interested if UpdateMany would be quicker. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MongoDB 4.2 and above, you can do an [update with the aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#updatemany-behavior-aggregation-pipeline) as follows:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    {},
    [
        { $set: { my_list : "$my_array.my_key" } }
    ]
)
```

---

For the other versions however you would need to do two queries i.e. one to get the desired field through an aggregation operation and the other query to update the documents:

```
const docs = db.collection.aggregate([ { $project:  { my_list : "$my_array.my_key" } } ])


const ops = []
docs.forEach(({ my_list }) => { 
    ops.push( { 
        'updateMany': {
            'filter': {},
            'update': { '$set': { my_list } }
        }
    })

    if ( ops.length === 500 ) {
        db.collection.bulkWrite(ops);
        ops = []
    }
})

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
    db.collection.bulkWrite(ops)
}
```